# Accessing method from specific included module

Tags: ruby

I have this setup:

```
module FirstModule
  def foo(arg)
    23 + arg + @private_variable
  end
end

module SecondModule
  def foo(arg)
    24 + arg + @private_variable
  end
end

class Foo
  include FirstModule
  include SecondModule

  def initialize
    @private_variable = 0
  end

  def access_place
    # call FirstModule#foo(1)
    puts foo(1)
  end
end


Foo.new.access_place
```

I am trying to access `FirstModule#foo`. I was wondering if there is any way to do so or if you have any other sugggestion. It is important that both methods in this modules have the same name and have access to some private data, so using `module_function` is not an option.

Comment: *"It is important that both methods in this modules have the same name"* Why?

Comment: The setup is more complex, we are talking about some legacy code.Here I have given only the concrete example, to be as clear as possible.

Comment: `FirstModule::foo(1)` will not work. First it is not an class method and second it must have access to private data, which means make it `module_function` will not solve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`alias_method`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Module.html#method-i-alias_method) to keep the overridden method:

```
class Foo
  include FirstModule
  alias_method :first_foo, :foo
  include SecondModule

  def access_place
    first_foo(1)   # FirstModule#foo
    foo(1)         # SecondModule#foo
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the specific module's method, bind it to `self` and then call it.

```
method = FirstModule.instance_method(:foo)
method.bind(self).call
```

Answer (score 0):

Found another solution wihout polluting my class. Using `Module#instance_method`:

```
FirstModule.instance_method(:foo).bind(self).call(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Modules are a way how to add methods to the object lookup path. If you include two modules that define method with the same name and list of parameters, only the last defined method will be used.